# WordPress Menu with Superslide show

Tags: wordpress

We are using the WordPress with Superslide show, the problem is menu is hiding behind the slide show how can we avoid thisand get the menu above the slide show?

http://eaglesnestbe.neurospeech.com/site/?page_id=515

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try increasing the z-index value of the menu.